# "javascript:;" for href attribute in HTML anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

**Update**

What does the code below mean and do? It needs JavaScript to work?

```
<a href="javascript:;">Do Somthing</a>
```

**Update**

Is equal to below?:

```
<a href="">Do Somthing</a>
```

Comment: AFAIK That means "do nothing"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using "javascript:" as the start of a href attribute to a link tells the javascript engine to use the rest of the string to be interpreted as javascript. In this case, it would cause a syntax error in strict interpretation, since this is effectively an empty javascript line with a closing semicolon. Like this:

```
;
```

Most browsers won't throw an error, however, as javascript on links are old syntax and should be avoided when possible. You could safely use it as a link that does nothing, however I wouldn't recommend it.

If you want a link to do nothing, you could use this instead:

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>
<a href="javascript:return false;">Link</a>
```

Using an empty href string will make the browser interpret it as a relative link. URLs that don't start with a protocol or an identifier like a high level domain or IP address will be treated as relative links. For example, the link `"index.htm"` on the domain `"google.com"` will create the link `"google.com/index.htm"`. In the same way, the href string `""` will create the link `"google.com/"` and so empty href strings will cause the browser to navigate to a new page.

Normally a link will not show the pointer cursor or format the element like a link if you do not specify a href attribute, this is so you can use it as an "anchor" element that you can link to using the hash character in a URL. Such as `"http://google.com/#an_anchor"` will take you to an anchor similar to this: `<a id="an_anchor">This is an anchor</a>`

However you can use CSS to force the link to be formatted, like this:

CSS:

```
a {
    color: #00c;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a>This is a link.</a>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/J3RfH/

Comment: Will those three anchors cause the page jump to the top of the page?

Comment: The `<a href="#">` link will in most cases cause the page to scroll to the top.

Answer (score 6):

It is a no-op.

The other common way is `href="#"` but that requires you to `return false` in the onclick event to avoid jumping to the top of the page and getting a `#` in the address bar.

Note that it is usually a good idea to have a link work both with and without JavaScript, i.e. do something like `<a href="/whatever" onclick="dowhatever(); return false;">` so people without JavaScript will simply open the page in the classic way while people with JavaScript get whatever nice stuff you did with JS.

If something isn't supposed to work without JavaScript at all, i.e. there is no useful `href` value, consider not using the `a` tag at all but use a `span` with a proper style (`cursor:pointer` and possibly underlined).

Answer (score 0):

It does nothing and is meant to replace default behavior of `a` tag to go somewhere with no-op, making link essentially unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

if you will specify some function after `:` then it will be called using `<a>` tag.But here you have not specified any function so nothing will happen