# Meaning of HTML <a> element with href="javascript:;"

Tags: javascript, html

I occasionally see an HTML `<a>` element whose `href` attribute is a URI that has just `javascript` for the scheme, and an empty statement `;` for the path.

- What is the purpose of this?
- Is it the same as `href="javascript:void(0);"`?
- Is it the same as having no `href` attribute at all?
- Is it the same as having no `<a>` element at all?

**Update**

The precise content that I am seeing is `<a href="javascript:;" style="cursor: default;"></a>`. So is this just a way of controlling the cursor graphic?

Comment: Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: 1. The purpose is to have an anchor element with no default HTML action 2. yes 3. yes 4. no, because you can still use the anchor with (for example) onclick event handlers or click event listeners

Comment: Regarding the last bullet point: How can _"Having an `<a>`"_ possibly be the same as _"Not having an `<a>`"_?

Comment: @Cerbrus: In the same way that `<div>text</div>` is the same as `text`, except for any CSS implications

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions of duplicate questions, but neither address `href="javascript:;"`. If it is the same as `href="#"` or `href="javascript:void(0)"` then please write that as an answer, but I see no duplicate of this specific question

Answer (score 6):

You can understand by below some steps:

```
<a onclick="foo()">Next Image</a>
<a href="#" onclick="foo()">Next Image</a>
<a href="javascript:foo()">Next Image</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="foo()">Next Image</a>
<a href="#" onclick="foo(); return false;">Next Image</a>
```

method 1 usually won't change the mouse cursor to a "hand cursor", so maybe it is not as desirable in some cases.

method 2 seems to cause the page to shift to a new location sometimes on IE 6 and IE 7. (to top of page?)

method 3 ... should work... but is it an old school way and should be avoided for modern browsers?

method 4 should work well.void-the-void/
the author seems to suggest it may break sometimes and try never to use `href="javascript:[anything]"`

method 5 may work the best? according to the article above, that may be the best way as it doesn't use `href="javascript:[something]"` and the return false part will cause the href="#" not to be evaluted, so that's the best way? thanks very much!

Comment: Thank you. Where does `<a href="javascript:;"></a>` fit into this scheme?

Comment: href="" will link to the same page as the one you are currently on, effectively refreshing the page. href="#" will not refresh the page, but using the # will make the screen move to the top of the page (it is the browser effectively looking for an anchor with no name, ). javascript:void(0) will prevent anything happening on the link at all.

Comment: Thank you again, but you haven't addressed my question about `href="javascript:;"`

Comment: When we create a link for solve our purpose to run JavaScript code, there are 2 ways to write the code. Which is better, in terms of functionality, page load speed, validation purposes, etc?
<a href="#" onclick="myJsFunc();">Run JavaScript Code</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Run JavaScript Code</a>

Comment: I understand, but you still haven't mentioned `href="javascript:;"`. Where does it fit into this scheme?

Comment: Here is an earlier answer on SO regarding the semicolon usage (that's not valid JavaScript, and can cause an error on some browsers)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880996/javascript-for-href-attribute-in-html-anchor-tag